# How do I fetch feed info from cache instead of directly from feed?

Tags: cache, feed, simplepie

I have been using SimplePie to fetch items from a feed and display them on an aside section on my site. I didn't notice before, but this was increasing the load time of the site by over 10 seconds. The reason I believe is that I haven't been using cache, so every time someone entered the site they would access/download the feed all over again.

So I set up a cronjob as the [documentation](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/setting_up_a_cron_job_with_simplepie) told me. Creating `update_simplepie_cache.php` in public_html. This worked and the cron job has created a file in `public_html/cache/`.

**The question is - how do I change my current markup to fetch info from the cache instead of directly from the feed?**

Here's the markup I have been using (this is in front-page.php)

```
<?php 
require_once  (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-feed.php');
$feed_url = 'feed://nordiccoffeeculture.com/feed/';
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feed_url);
$feed->init();
?>

<?php foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 6) as $item): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nordic-blog-item">
        <?php 
        $rss_image = ($item->get_item_tags('', 'image'));

        if ($rss_image) { ?>
            <a class="recent-blog-img-link" href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><img srcset="<?php print $rss_image[0]['data']; ?>"/></a><?php 
        } else { ?>
            <!-- takes the first image of the RSS item content, and displays it -->
            <a class="recent-blog-img-link" href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><img srcset="<?php get_first_image_url($item->get_content()); ?>"/></a><?php 
        }?>
        <h3><a href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php print $item->get_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php echo shorten($item->get_description(), 50); ?><br>
        <span class="nordic-date"><?php echo date_i18n('F j, Y', $item->get_date('U')); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [`fetch_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) that implements it's own extension of `SimplePie_Cache`:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
...
$feed->set_cache_class( 'WP_Feed_Cache' );
...
$feed->set_feed_url( $url );
...
$feed->set_cache_duration( apply_filters( 
    'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, $url ) );
```

that caches the feeds with `set_transient()`.

Comment: Hei @birgire, thanks for the answer. This seems good, but after updating the code to include this it stops working. Doing a `print_r` of the `$feed` object gives me `[error] => cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 3258 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. This worked brilliantly :) For anyone who wondered about the curl error, I needed to change the feed url from `feed:nord..` to `http://nord..`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, thanks for the update @turtledropbomb